# integrate from 0 to a variable in r

Tags: r, variables, integral

I would like to plot y against z, where y=(1+z)*int_0^z((0.3*(1+z')^3+0.7)^-1/2)dz',

where int_0^z just means integrate from 0 to z.
I figured I should first integrate from 0 to z, and then use the integral result to plug into the equation. Here is my code:

```
integrand <- function(z1) {(0.3*(1+z1)^3+0.7)^-1/2}
integral<-integrate(integrand, lower = 0, upper = z)
```

but this error appears:

> Error: object 'any_number' not found
>
> Error in integrate(integrand, lower = 0, upper = z) : 
>     object 'z' not found"

How do I define `z` here?

Thanks,

Jade

Comment: Something like `z <- any_number` before `integrate`?

Comment: Please edit your post to show the same error after you defined `z`.

Comment: Well, if you had actually given 'z' a value then you might have achieved something.

Comment: OP shld prbly [re]read https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html too (I fear the outcome won't be what's expected it to be with current parentical placement.

Comment: @BondedDust no this integration is part of the function I'm going to use later so z doesn't refer to a particular value

Comment: OK, I see. I give up.

Comment: @Jade: you made my day, thanks for the laugh. This is so very similar to the Windows "Press any key" thing, and the response "where is the 'any' key?" Try replacing your literal "any_number" with ... a number. It works. The fact that you claim it "doesn't refer to a particular value" indicates you have many other issues here, starting with your understanding of writing and interacting with functions. (Impressive, though: you've received responses from three prominent SO "R" contributors/gurus. If any of these three suggest something, I recommend taking it as near-gospel.)

Comment: @r2evans. First of all I feel very honored to be replied by many of the top writers.... Second the function I'm going to plot is actually y= (1+z)integral_0^z((0.3*(1+x)^3+0.7)^-1/2), so I don't have any values to give to z. I'm really confused here.

Comment: First, you are writing a function, great. Though there are times when using uninitialized variables in *R* is allowable and perhaps even good practice, I do not believe this is one of them. Perhaps if you provide some context in your question (not in a comment, please) by showing a sufficient portion of the function that (a) ensures `z` is a valid variable, and (b) uses `integral(...)` with these `x`, `y`, and `z` variables. This goes back to [making a good reproducible question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Nope, still not clear. Do you already know how you will plot it? Is there a particular plotting function you will be using? Or are using base plotting functions like `points`, `lines`, or even `polygon`, and haven't figured out how to incorporate this nebulous "z" into the fold? Is the plan to show a cumulative density function?

Comment: @r2evans oh sorry I made a typo. It should be all about y and z no x. so for integral part I'll get a function which has z, and after multiplying by (1+z) I get relationship between y and z. I'm using curve function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93443/discussion-between-jade-and-r2evans).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give it a try.

```
integrand <- function(z1) {(0.3*(1+z1)^3+0.7)^-1/2}
```

We need to make `integral` a function of z, ensure that it only returns the value of the integral, and that it is vectorized in `z`:

```
integral <- Vectorize(function(z) integrate(integrand, lower = 0, upper = z)$value)
```

Now we can test it:

```
integral(1:2)
#[1] 0.3056435 0.4037815
```

And plot:

```
curve(integral, 0, 10, xname = "z")
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: so if I want to plot y=integral*(1+z), I just use integral <- Vectorize(function(z) (1+z)*(integrate(integrand, lower = 0, upper = z)$value)) right? That gives me a straight line. I'm not sure if it's right.

Comment: @Jade It's not a straight line. Change the axis limits, e.g., `curve(integral, 0, 1e10, xname = "z")`. (And of course, you can always check by solving the integral.)